# dark screen on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, screen

I'm having problem with my application on iPhone 3GS. I've created a little game, that's working fine on iPhone 3G. But apple rejected it. They've told me, that the screen is too dark and everything's hard to see because of it.
Do you have any ideas what could cause that?
Thanks for every reply.

I'm sorry but I'm not allowed to post images here directly, it's there.

http://i48.tinypic.com/2cy4qh5.jpg

Comment: Ok, I'll post screenshots as soon as possible, till today's evening, only need to search my e-mails. (apple sent some)

Comment: Does it look like that in the iPhone simulator?

Comment: Another edit, now the image is difference between 3G and 3GS. The bright one is result tested on my 3G, the dark one is result that apple sent me, tested on 3GS. Wow I've tested it on simulator right now and it's also dark =-O. Do you know what the problem could be?
(don't think about last item in the menu, there's little difference, but it's not important, it's only different text and I've tested this, it's not source of my problem).

Comment: Is this an OpenGL-ES-based application?  There may be something different in the way rendering is handled between the iPhone 3G and the 3GS and desktop.  The latter two support OpenGL ES 2.0, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something might be changing your opacity on your view.  And as your opacity goes down, your window or underlying view's black background shows through.

Of course, it could also be a view on top that is black and has its opacity changed so it doesn't display the view below.

I could go on and on with different scenarios that could cause this.  You have the code and you need to map out your view hierarchy, including the MainWindow, and determine which one has a black or dark background (or foreground) and then see how that is bleeding through.

Once you know that, it will be a lot easier to figure out why it has a problem on some devices/Simulator but not on your iPhone.

Comment: I know what you thienk and it's a good idea. Thanks a lot. I'll try to figure it out. I'll reply here after it.

Comment: Problem solved. It was problem with lightning. The same lightning settings takes different effect on 3G and 3GS. Only thing that I needed to do was to disable lightning at all.
In fact I don't know why I enabled it before, because I don't need it in my application.
Thanks for all the replies.